# Why is PowerShell resolving paths from $home instead of the current directory?

Tags: powershell

I expect this little powershell one liner to echo a full path to foo.txt, where the directory is my current directory.

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\foo.txt")
```

But it's not.  It prints...

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\foo.txt
```

I am not in the $home directory.  Why is it resolving there?

Comment: you should be using Resolve-Path within powershell.

Comment: On some systems it returns relative to c:\Windows\system32.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`[System.IO.Path]` is using the shell process' current directory. You can get the absolute path with the `Resolve-Path` cmdlet:

```
Resolve-Path .\foo.txt
```

Comment: This behaviour is unintuitive and inconsistent with every other shell-scripting system on the planet. Of course.  Thank you StackOverflow users like Shay, for helping us mere humans understand Powershell!

Comment: The drawback of `Resolve-Path` is that it can resolve only paths that actually exist.

Comment: Ah.  So to glob or expand a path you plan to create, you can not use it.

Comment: If we want to resolve a path that doesn't exist yet, we can use [System.IO.Path]::Combine((Get-Location), $relativePath).

Answer (score 13):

According to the documentation for [GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx), it uses the current working directory to resolve the absolute path. The powershell current working directory is not the same as the current location:

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
C:\Documents and Settings\user
PS C:\> get-location

Path
----
C:\
```

I suppose you could use SetCurrentDirectory to get them to match:

```
PS C:\> [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($(get-location))
PS C:\> [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\foo.txt")
C:\foo.txt
```

Comment: I have my prompt function do this, updating the current working directory.

Comment: This will only work if the current location is in the filesystem. Check $PWD.Provider.Name first.

Comment: correct way without provider name checking:

    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory=(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath