# Why don't .NET objects in PowerShell use the current directory?

Tags: powershell

When you use a .NET object from PowerShell, and it takes a filename, it always seems to be relative to `C:\Windows\System32`.

For example:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText('hello.txt', 'Hello World')
```

...will write `C:\Windows\System32\hello.txt`, rather than `C:\Current\Directory\hello.txt`

Why does PowerShell do this? Can this behaviour be changed? If it can't be changed, how do I work around it?

I've tried `Resolve-Path`, but that only works with files that already exist, and it's far too verbose to be doing all the time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reasons PowerShell doesn't keep the .NET notion of current working directory in sync with PowerShell's notion of the working dir are:

1. PowerShell working dirs can be in a provider that isn't even file system
   based e.g. HKLM:\Software
2. A single PowerShell process can have
   multiple runspaces.  Each runspace can be cd`d into a different file
   system location. However the .NET/process "working directory" is
   essentially a global for the process and wouldn't work for a
   scenario where there can be multiple working dirs (one per runspace).

Comment: Fair enough. Can the normal PowerShell process have multiple runspaces?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe It's not very common AFAICT for PowerShell.exe to use multiple runspaces but the PowerShell engine provides the capability. Other hosts like PowerShell_ISE and PowerGUI take advantage of multiple runspaces within a single process. Fire up ISE, press Ctrl+T (new powershell tab) and run $pid followed by $ExecutionContext.Host.Runspace.InstanceId in each tab. Notice the process id is the same but the runspace id is different.

Answer (score 33):

You can change .net working dir to powershell working dir: 
 `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath` 
After this line all .net methods like `[io.path]::GetFullPath` and `[IO.File]::WriteAllText` will work without problems

Comment: ~~Why is this necessary? Why isn't `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` synchronized to `$PWD` by default?~~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248149/9731176

Answer (score 7):

For convenience, I added the following to my `prompt` function, so that it runs whenever a command finishes:

```
# Make .NET's current directory follow PowerShell's
# current directory, if possible.
if ($PWD.Provider.Name -eq 'FileSystem') {
    [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($PWD)
}
```

This is not necessarily a *great* idea, because it means that some scripts (that assume that the Win32 working directory tracks the PowerShell working directory) will work on my machine, but not necessarily on others.

Comment: A link to a complete prompt function with the fix would be nice.  Gist?

Comment: https://github.com/rlipscombe/WindowsPowerShell/blob/master/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1#L66-L69

Answer (score 4):

When you use filenames in .Net methods, the best practice is to use fully-qualified path names. Or use

```
$pwd\foo.cer
```

If you do in powershell console from:

```
C:\> [Environment]::CurrentDirectory

C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

you can see what folder .net use.

Comment: Fair enough in scripts. Gets old real quick on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because PowerShell is running in System32.  When you cd to a directory in PowerShell, it doesn't actually change the working directory of powershell.exe.

See:

[PowerTip article on syncing the two directories](http://s1403.t.en25.com/e/es.aspx?s=1403&e=55258&elq=1d6dca6847e7403c9f132b50b599cb89)

[Channel9 forum thread](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/249957-PowerShell-and-the-current-directory/)

Comment: Turns out that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071775/why-is-powershell-resolving-paths-from-home-instead-of-the-current-directory, but because I'm running elevated, it's not $HOME.

Comment: Yep, that would do it - though if you weren't elevated and you did `cd $folder` you would be operating on `$HOME`.  But basically that's why it wasn't respecting $PWD - because that code was effectively asking Windows for the process working directory, but the $PWD variable is a PowerShell artifact, not a Windows one.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a long time ago and now I add the following to the beginning of my profile:

```
# Setup user environment when running session under alternate credentials and
# logged in as a normal user.
if ((Get-PSProvider FileSystem).Home -eq "")
{
    Set-Variable HOME $env:USERPROFILE -Force
    $env:HOMEDRIVE = Split-Path $HOME -Qualifier
    $env:HOMEPATH = Split-Path $HOME -NoQualifier
    (Get-PSProvider FileSystem).Home = $HOME
    Set-Location $HOME
}
```

Comment: That answers why it's System32, in my comment, thanks; but it doesn't directly answer the question.