# Check if a file exists or not in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this script which compares files in two areas of the disk and copies the latest file over the one with the older modified date.

```
$filestowatch=get-content C:\H\files-to-watch.txt

$adminFiles=dir C:\H\admin\admin -recurse | ? { $fn=$_.FullName; ($filestowatch | % {$fn.contains($_)}) -contains $True}

$userFiles=dir C:\H\user\user -recurse | ? { $fn=$_.FullName; ($filestowatch | % {$fn.contains($_)}) -contains $True}

foreach($userfile in $userFiles)
{

      $exactadminfile= $adminfiles | ? {$_.Name -eq $userfile.Name} |Select -First 1
      $filetext1=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($exactadminfile.FullName)
      $filetext2=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($userfile.FullName)
      $equal = $filetext1 -ceq $filetext2 # case sensitive comparison

      if ($equal) { 
        Write-Host "Checking == : " $userfile.FullName 
        continue; 
      } 

      if($exactadminfile.LastWriteTime -gt $userfile.LastWriteTime)
      {
         Write-Host "Checking != : " $userfile.FullName " >> user"
         Copy-Item -Path $exactadminfile.FullName -Destination $userfile.FullName -Force
       }
       else
       {
          Write-Host "Checking != : " $userfile.FullName " >> admin"
          Copy-Item -Path $userfile.FullName -Destination $exactadminfile.FullName -Force
       }
}
```

Here is the format of files-to-watch.txt

```
content\less\_light.less
content\less\_mixins.less
content\less\_variables.less
content\font-awesome\variables.less
content\font-awesome\mixins.less
content\font-awesome\path.less
content\font-awesome\core.less
```

I would like to modify this so that it avoids doing this if the file does not exist in both areas and prints a warning message.  Can someone tell me how I can check if a file exists using PowerShell?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Just to offer [the alternative](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) to the [`Test-Path` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177015.aspx) (since nobody mentioned it):

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists($path)
```

Does (almost) the same thing as

```
Test-Path $path -PathType Leaf
```

except no support for wildcard characters

Comment: See also: [A better way to check if a file exists or not in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31888581/450913)

Comment: @orad Yes, I saw it, posted an answer with a negated Exists() call, but was not met with the same positive response ;-)

Comment: Using `[System.IO.File]::Exists` also [resolves relative paths differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11246068/1394393), and `Test-Path` can be used with non-filepaths (e.g., registry locations). Use `Test-Path`.

Comment: The Exists() one didn't work for me with relative paths. Test-Path worked great.

Comment: @Jamie Native .NET methods usually resolve paths relative to the working directory of the process, not necessarily the current FileSystem path in powershell. You could do `[System.IO.File]::($(Join-Path $PWD $path))`

Comment: And in case you didn't guess it's `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path)` for folders.  Both support UNC paths on my system, but to do hidden shares remember to escape the `$` in the path as "`$"

Comment: This will return `$False` if a file is hidden. At least for me anyway.

Answer (score 121):

Use [Test-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx):

```
if (!(Test-Path $exactadminfile) -and !(Test-Path $userfile)) {
  Write-Warning "$userFile absent from both locations"
}
```

Placing the above code in your `ForEach` loop should do what you want

Answer (score 45):

You want to use `Test-Path`:

```
Test-Path <path to file> -PathType Leaf
```

Answer (score 16):

The standard way to see if a file exists is with the `Test-Path` cmdlet.

```
Test-Path -path $filename
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `Test-Path` cmd-let. So something like...

```
if(!(Test-Path [oldLocation]) -and !(Test-Path [newLocation]))
{
    Write-Host "$file doesn't exist in both locations."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cls

$exactadminfile = "C:\temp\files\admin" #First folder to check the file

$userfile = "C:\temp\files\user" #Second folder to check the file

$filenames=Get-Content "C:\temp\files\files-to-watch.txt" #Reading the names of the files to test the existance in one of the above locations

foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
  if (!(Test-Path $exactadminfile\$filename) -and !(Test-Path $userfile\$filename)) { #if the file is not there in either of the folder
    Write-Warning "$filename absent from both locations"
  } else {
    Write-Host " $filename  File is there in one or both Locations" #if file exists there at both locations or at least in one location
  }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Test-Path may give odd answer. E.g. "Test-Path c:\temp\ -PathType leaf" gives false, but "Test-Path c:\temp* -PathType leaf" gives true. Sad :(