# Powershell check if file exists

Tags: powershell

I have the below PowerShell script called via a SSIS Process Task to check if a file is locked - how do I modify so it checks if the file exists first.

- If it does not exist, then exit with 999
- If it does exist but is locked, then exit with 999
- If it does exist and is not locked, then exit with 0

  ```
  $file = "\\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxxx\task_status.log"    
  try { [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close();exit 0 } catch { exit 999}
  ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879814/check-if-a-file-exists-or-not-in-windows-powershell

Comment: How is this a duplicate if the other post is also about copying - mine is about checking if it exists AND if its locked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$file = "\\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxxx\task_status.log"
if (Test-Path -path $file)
{ 
    try { [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close();return 0 } catch { return 999}
}
else
{
    return 999
}
```

Comment: I don't get a 0 if the file exists but is not locked?

Comment: If the file exist it will use your old try/catch and exit with the same code as before. If the file doesn't exist it will return 999.

Comment: How come I don't get a 0 if the file exists and is not locked?  I have tried it in Powershell

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work if I open the log in MS Word - I should be expecting to see 999?  It just returns nothing in Powershell

Comment: I only get a 999 if the file does not exist.

Comment: Try changing the exit 0 and exit 999 to return 0 and return 999.