# Executing a file that may reside at two different locations using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0

I have a cute little script in my *$PROFILE* helping me start Notepad++ from the script showing a file of my choosing.

```
function Edit{
  param([string]$file = " ")
  Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -ArgumentList $file
}
```

It's worked great until recently, where I jump between different systems. I discovered that NPP is installed in *C:\Program Files* on some systems but in *C:\Program Files (x86)* on others. I can edit the script adapting it but having done so a gazillion times (i.e. 5 to this point), I got sick and tired of it, realizing that I have to automate this insanity.

Knowing little about scripting, I wonder what I should Google for. Does best practice dictate using [exception handling](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell) in such a case or is it more appropriate to go for [conditional expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881297/1525840)?

According to *Get-Host | Select-Object Version* I'm running version 5.1, if it's of any significance. Perhaps there's an even neater method I'm unaware of? Relying on an environment variable? I'd also prefer to not use a method valid in an older version of PS, although working, if there's a more convenient approach in a later one. (And given my experience on the subject, I can't tell a duck from a goose.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use conditionals for this one.
One option is to test the path directly if you know for certain it is in a particular location.

Hard coded paths:

```
function Edit{
  param([string]$file = " ")

$32bit = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
$64bit = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

if (Test-Path $32bit) {Start-Process -FilePath $32bit -ArgumentList $file}
elseif (Test-Path $64bit) {Start-Process -FilePath $64bit -ArgumentList $file}
else {Write-Error -Exception "NotePad++ not found."}
}
```

Another option is pulling path information from registry keys, if they're available:

```
function Edit{
  param([string]$file = " ")

$32bit = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Notepad++\' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).("(default)")
$64bit = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Notepad++\' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).("(default)")

if ($32bit) {Start-Process -FilePath "$32bit\notepad++.exe" -ArgumentList $file}
elseif ($64bit) {Start-Process -FilePath "$64bit\notepad++.exe" -ArgumentList $file}
else {Write-Error -Exception "NotePad++ not found."}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the great help from @BoogaRoo (who should get some +1 for effort) and asked by the same to post my own version of the answer, I go against my reluctance to post asnwers to own questions due to strong sensation of tackiness.

My final version, taking into account systems that lack NP++ but still want to show the editor of **some** kind.

```
function Edit{
  param([string]$file = " ")

  $executable = "Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
  $32bit = "C:\Program Files (x86)\" + $executable
  $64bit = "C:\Program Files\" + $executable
  $target = "notepad"

  if(Test-Path $32bit) { $target = $32bit }
  if(Test-Path $64bit) { $target = $64bit }

  Start-Process $target -ArgumentList $file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer a streamlined version that also supports passing multiple files:

```
function Edit {

  param(
   # Allow passing multiple files, both with explicit array syntax (`,`-separated)
   # or as indiv. arguments.
   [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
   [string[]] $File
  )

  # Construct the potential Notepad++ paths.
  # Note: `-replace '$'` is a trick to append a string to each element
  #       of an array.
  $exePaths = $env:ProgramFiles, ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} -replace '$', '\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'

  # See which one, if any, exists, using Get-Command.
  $exeToUse = Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore $exePaths | Select-Object -First 1

  # Fall back to Notepad.
  if (-not $exeToUse) { $exeToUse = 'notepad.exe' }

  # Invoke whatever editor was found with the optional file(s).
  # Note that both Notepad++ and NotePad can be invoked directly
  # without blocking subsequent commands, so there is no need for `Start-Process`,
  # whose argument processing is buggy.
  & $exeToUse $File

}
```

- An *array* of potential executable paths is passed to [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command), which returns a command-info object for each actual executable found, if any.

  - `-ErrorAction Ignore` quietly ignores any errors.
  - `Select-Object -First 1` extracts the *first* command-info object, if present, from the `Get-Command` output; this is necessary to guard against the (perhaps unlikely) case where the executable exists in *both* locations.
- `$exeToUse` receives `$null` (effectively) if `Get-Command` produces no output, in which case Boolean expression `-not $exeToUse` evaluates to `$true`, causing the fallback to `notepad.exe` to take effect.
- Both command *names* (strings) and *command-info objects* (instances of [`System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo) or derived classes, as returned by `Get-Command`) can be executed via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).