# PowerShell - Trim File Names Before and After Underscores Works For Small Sets of Files

Tags: powershell, special-characters, file-rename, character-trimming

This is my first endeavor into using PowerShell, but I have a folder that contains several hundred files like the ones shown below.

- Timestamp#1_File_Name_of_the_Item_a650-d322205a2071.xls
- Timestamp#1_File_Name_of_the_Item_a650-d3b580442072.txt
- Timestamp#1_File_Name_of_the_Item_a650-d3bhnf5a2073.xlsx
- Timestamp#1_File_Name_of_the_Item_a650-d3b523da2074.csv
- Timestamp#2_File_Name_of_the_Item_a650-d3bbvx5a2075.xls
- File_Name_of_the_Item_a650-d3ddfe5a2075.pdf

My end goal is to:

1. Trim everything before, including the first underscore

   a. unless it does not start with the datetime stamp
2. Trim everything after, including the last underscore but leave the extension
3. Replace the remaining underscores with a space
4. Find out why I can't use my existing code with the following files

20231025041306_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_7777d4cb-6666631f-fa38-473e-a650-d3564505a2075.xls 20231025041406_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_8777befd-87765c3e-3164-4800-b102-a82d48aaaa52.xlsx 20231025041436_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_73d2bbbc.PDF 20231025041518_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_210zzz2c.csv 20231025041613_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_aqqqq1ad.txt 20231025041906_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_a6fff0d3.xls 20231025041935_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_f37ggg89.pdf 20231025042000_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_9e812343.csv 20231025042026_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_d7522280.txt 20231025042229_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_37gggd7-5e81ffhgedc77-4c8e-9fbc-d2996ggg0df1.xls 20231025042254_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_4fjjjfrgb-e3ec7993-92d7-4ab8-ad9e-83ejjjjj929b.xlsx 20231025042329_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_c0fkkkkf2.pdf 20231025042410_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_b555tefd7f.csv 20231025042505_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_9784g07e.txt 20231025042747_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_2902e487-cc3c6chhhh074-4a2e-a97f-bfa0000a062e.xls 20231025042813_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_aab84122-2fzzzz68-a706-49a5-a3ef-40030ffff0a3.xlsx 20231025042842_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_79cdgggd2.PDF 20231025042923_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_f07yyya8f.csv 20231025043220_Tttt_Dddddd_Rrrrrr_2444gr18d-13b4fb14-8fc2-45e0-b18b-59jkh6353d78.xlsx

For some reason, if I try my code with all of the files, then I get the results on the left. But, if I remove any one of the files, then I get the correct results on the right.

| All at Once | One file is removed |
| --- | --- |
| LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.xls | LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.xls |
| LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.xlsx | LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.xlsx |
| LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.pdf | LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.pdf |
| LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.csv | LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.csv |
| LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.txt | LLLLL Aaaaaaaa.txt |
| dddddd.xls | cccc dddddd rrrrrr.xls |
| dddddd.pdf | cccc dddddd rrrrrr.pdf |
| dddddd.csv | cccc dddddd rrrrrr.csv |
| dddddd.txt | cccc dddddd rrrrrr.txt |
| OO.csv | LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.csv |
| OO.pdf | LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.pdf |
| OO.txt | LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.txt |
| OO.xls | LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.xls |
| OO.xlsx | LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.xlsx |
| Rrrrr.csv | Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.csv |
| Rrrrr.pdf | Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.pdf |
| Rrrrr.xls | Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.xls |
| Rrrrr.xlsx | Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.xlsx |
| Tttt Dddddd Rrrrrr.xlsx | Tttt_Dddddd_Rrrrrr.xlsx |

```
#My Code that I hobbled together from other posts
$path = “c:\\folder 1”

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path –File | ForEach-Object {
$items = $_.BaseName –split “_”
$newFileName = ($items\[1..($items.Length – 2)\] -join “_”) + $_.Extension
Rename-Item –Path $_.FullName -NewName $newFileName
}
Get-ChildItem -File $Path | Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name -replace “\_”, “ “}
```

So far I can get most everything to work but the following:

1. For some reason, with the files below, the code seems to remove more characters than it should. If any one of the files is removed, then all of the files work.
2. Not to remove the characters if there is no datetime stamp
3. Skip/rename the file if it is a duplicate

Comment: what are the valid timestamps? only `yyyyMMddHHmmss` or there can be different formats? if so, you need to clarify on the valid formats

Comment: "Skip/rename the file if it is a duplicate", see: [Check if a file exists or not in Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879814/check-if-a-file-exists-or-not-in-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

This approach might work for you, it's unclear though what are the valid formats for your timestamps. The regex in this example considers a timestamp as any file starting with 14 numeric digits followed by an underscore, this filtering would also be excluding any file not meeting this matching condition, thus not renamed.

A demo using the files names in question:

```bash
$test = [System.IO.FileInfo[]] @(
    '20231025041306_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_7777d4cb-6666631f-fa38-473e-a650-d3564505a2075.xls'
    '20231025041406_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_8777befd-87765c3e-3164-4800-b102-a82d48aaaa52.xlsx'
    '20231025041436_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_73d2bbbc.PDF'
    '20231025041518_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_210zzz2c.csv'
    '20231025041613_LLLLL_Aaaaaaaaaa_aqqqq1ad.txt'
    '20231025041906_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_a6fff0d3.xls'
    '20231025041935_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_f37ggg89.pdf'
    '20231025042000_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_9e812343.csv'
    '20231025042026_cccc_dddddd_rrrrrr_d7522280.txt'
    '20231025042229_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_37gggd7-5e81ffhgedc77-4c8e-9fbc-d2996ggg0df1.xls'
    '20231025042254_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_4fjjjfrgb-e3ec7993-92d7-4ab8-ad9e-83ejjjjj929b.xlsx'
    '20231025042329_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_c0fkkkkf2.pdf'
    '20231025042410_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_b555tefd7f.csv'
    '20231025042505_LllllAaaaaaaa_OO_OoooTttt_9784g07e.txt'
    '20231025042747_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_2902e487-cc3c6chhhh074-4a2e-a97f-bfa0000a062e.xls'
    '20231025042813_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_aab84122-2fzzzz68-a706-49a5-a3ef-40030ffff0a3.xlsx'
    '20231025042842_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_79cdgggd2.PDF'
    '20231025042923_Ppppp_Rrrrr_Rrrrrr_f07yyya8f.csv'
    '20231025043220_Tttt_Dddddd_Rrrrrr_2444gr18d-13b4fb14-8fc2-45e0-b18b-59jkh6353d78.xlsx'
)

$test |
    Where-Object BaseName -Match '(?<=^[0-9]{14}_).+(?=_)' |
    ForEach-Object { $Matches[0].Replace('_', ' ') + $_.Extension }
```

This would output:

```
LLLLL Aaaaaaaaaa.xls
LLLLL Aaaaaaaaaa.xlsx
LLLLL Aaaaaaaaaa.PDF
LLLLL Aaaaaaaaaa.csv
LLLLL Aaaaaaaaaa.txt
cccc dddddd rrrrrr.xls
cccc dddddd rrrrrr.pdf
cccc dddddd rrrrrr.csv
cccc dddddd rrrrrr.txt
LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.xls
LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.xlsx
LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.pdf
LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.csv
LllllAaaaaaaa OO OoooTttt.txt
Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.xls
Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.xlsx
Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.PDF
Ppppp Rrrrr Rrrrrr.csv
Tttt Dddddd Rrrrrr.xlsx
```

If this is what you're looking for then the final code would become:

```bash
Get-ChildItem path\to\theFiles -File |
    Where-Object BaseName -Match '(?<=^[0-9]{14}_).+(?=_)' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $Matches[0].Replace('_', ' ') + $_.Extension }
```

See also https://regex101.com/r/YMd0IS/1 for regex details.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely allows me to go down a different path than where I was originally going! :)