# Powershell script uses the user's home directory as current working dir when using .NET ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory. How to fix?

Tags: powershell, zip

Here's my script (createdistro.ps1)

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

$source = "bin\Debug\"
$destination = "gwtester_signed.zip"

If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
```

Notice the error message I get from running the script:

```
PS C:\dev\DEV7\Test\gwtester> .\createdistro.ps1
Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "The file 'C:\Users\bbren\gwtester_signed.zip' already
exists."
At C:\dev\DEV7\Test\gwtester\createdistro.ps1:7 char:1
+ [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

As you can see, the script attempts to write to `C:\Users\bbren\gwtester_signed.zip`, but the current working directory is `C:\dev\etc\`.

The [documentation for ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx) states that "A relative path is interpreted as relative to the current working directory."

What is wrong?

Comment: Whats your PSversion and how do you call your script?

Comment: Current PowerShell location and current working directory is two different things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend $PSScriptRoot.

Try this:

`$destination = Join-Path (Get-Location) 'gwtester_signed.zip'`

But depending on your psversion, how about Expand-Archive?

Comment: OK. How would you do it if the destination file path was passed from the command line? To support both relative and absolute paths?

Comment: I ended up using Compress-Archive. But I would still like to understand how Powershell handles absolute and relative paths. I'm baffled as to why CreateFromDirectory uses the user's home directory, instead of the current working dir.

Comment: Why not `$PSScriptRoot`? I understand it as a variable containing the directory of the running script.

Comment: @gmsoulman your understanding is correct. I assume the user may not always want zip files to land in the script's folder.

Comment: @codeape afaik providing a relative path to .net objects in ps will be resolved relative to $env:userprofile. to support relative paths, you can use $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path). that will convert itself to a absolute path if required,.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$destination = "gwtester_signed.zip"` to `$destination = "$PSScriptRoot\gwtester_signed.zip"`

Answer (score 0):

I've actually added this to my prompt function to keep the .NET and Powershell view of what the current working directory is in sync. There's probably a load of reasons this is a BadIdea™ - but it works for me :

```
[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
```

Of course, you could just call that before you want to run a .NET method that cares about it too.

Edit: Ah yes, this question points out why this might end up being a bad idea :
[Why don't .NET objects in PowerShell use the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246068/why-dont-net-objects-in-powershell-use-the-current-directory)

Edit2: and in light of the above, I've now changed my prompt function to do this :

```
if($PWD.Provider.Name -eq 'Filesystem'){
    [System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
}
```

So that the attempt to update the .NET view of current directory only happens when the current Powershell provider is the Filesystem one.