# System.IO.FileInfo and Relative Paths

Tags: powershell, system.io.fileinfo

I was wondering if someone could help me understand why does [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) behaves differently on Windows than on Linux when handling relative paths.

#### Example

- On Linux

```bash
PS /home/user/Documents> ([System.IO.FileInfo]'./test.txt').FullName
/home/user/Documents/test.txt
```

- On Windows

```bash
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> ([System.IO.FileInfo]'.\test.txt').FullName
C:\Users\User\test.txt
```

---

#### EDIT

To clarify on the above, there is no difference on how `System.IO.FileInfo` handles relative paths on Windows or Linux. The issue is related to `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` not being updated by `Push-Location` or `Set-Location`.

A simple example:

```bash
PS /home/user> [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
/home/user
PS /home/user> cd ./Documents/
PS /home/user/Documents> [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
/home/user
```

---

And assuming this is a expected behavior, what would be an optimal way to approach our `param(...)` blocks on scripts and functions to accept both cases (absolute and relative). I used to type constraint the path parameter to `System.IO.FileInfo` but now I can see it is clearly wrong.

This is what I came across, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.
I believe `Split-Path -IsAbsolute` will also bring problems if working with Network Paths, please correct me if I'm wrong.

```bash
param(
    [ValidateScript({ 
        if(Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf) {
            return $true
        }
        throw 'Invalid File Path'
    })]
    [string] $Path
)

if(-not (Split-Path $Path -IsAbsolute)) {
    [string] $Path = Resolve-Path $Path
}
```

Comment: You could try `[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, '.\test.txt'))`

Comment: @Theo that's excellent and works fine on both OS. Would you ask `[IO.Path]::IsRooted(..)` before or just do it no matter what? I guess I wont find an answer on the behavior of `FileInfo` on Windows vs Linux so you can propose this as an answer and if by the end of the day nobody can answer the other question I'll go ahead an accept it. Thanks Theo.

Comment: This has been discussed before.  For example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246068/why-dont-net-objects-in-powershell-use-the-current-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels a bit duplicate, but since you asked..

I'm sorry I don't know about Linux, but in Windows:

You can add a test first to see if the path is relative and if so, convert it to absolute like:

```
$Path = '.\test.txt'
if (![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Path) -or $Path -match '^\\[^\\]+') {
    $Path =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, $Path))
}
```

<sup>I added `$Path -match '^\\[^\\]+'` to also convert relative paths starting with a backslash like `\ReadWays.ps1` meaning the path starts at the root directory. UNC paths that start with two backslashes are regarded as absolute.</sup>

---

Apparently (I really have no idea why..) the above does not work on Linux, because there, when using a UNC path, the part `![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted('\\server\folder')` yields **`True`**.

It seems then you need to check the OS first and do the check differently on Linux.

```
$Path = '\\server\share'

if ($IsWindows) {  # $IsWindows exists in version 7.x. Older versions do `$env:OS -match 'Windows'`
    if (![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Path) -or $Path -match '^\\[^\\]+') {
        $Path =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, $Path))
    }
}
else {
    if ($Path -notlike '\\*\*') {  # exclude UNC paths as they are not relative
        if (![System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Path) -or $Path -match '^\\[^\\]+') {
            $Path =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, $Path))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest alternative would be to use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path?view=powershell-7.2) to:

- Handle UNC, Relative, Absolute and Rooted Paths.
- Be compatible with Windows and Linux
- Be efficient

Another neat option if we are using [`[cmdletbinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=The%20CmdletBinding%20attribute%20is%20an,the%20parameters%20of%20compiled%20cmdlets.) is to use [`$PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(..)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.getunresolvedproviderpathfrompspath?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0):

```bash
function Test-ResolvePath {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param($path)
    $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($path)
}

Test-ResolvePath \\server01\test         # => \\server01\test
Test-ResolvePath C:\Users\user\Documents # => C:\Users\user\Documents
Test-ResolvePath C:Documents             # => C:\Documents
(Test-ResolvePath .) -eq $PWD.Path       # => True
(Test-ResolvePath ~) -eq $HOME           # => True
```

---

If we're looking to emulate the behavior of most [Microsoft.PowerShell.Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/?view=powershell-7.3) cmdlets, having a `-LiteralPath` and `-Path` the code would be a bit more complex and the APIs being called are also different, [`PathIntrinsics.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PathIntrinsics.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) for literal path validation and [`PSCmdlet.GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.getresolvedproviderpathfrompspath?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) for wildcard path validation. Both methods ensure that the target exists.

```bash
function Test-ResolvePath {
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Path')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPath', Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string] $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Path', Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string] $Path
    )

    $provider = $null

    try {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'LiteralPath') {
            $resolvedPath = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(
                $LiteralPath,
                [ref] $provider,
                [ref] $null)
        }
        else {
            $resolvedPath = $PSCmdlet.GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(
                $Path,
                [ref] $provider)
        }

        foreach ($path in $resolvedPath) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Path             = $path
                Provider         = $provider
                IsFileSystemPath = $provider.ImplementingType -eq [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider]
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
    }
}

Test-ResolvePath $pwd\*
Test-ResolvePath HKLM:
Test-ResolvePath -LiteralPath Cert:
Test-ResolvePath doesnotexist
```

Comment: hi @BitcoinMurderousManiac thanks for the upvote, I'm not sure about a post but I have 2 modules that outputs trees: https://github.com/santisq/PSTree & https://github.com/santisq/PSADTree

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what it was `Get-PSTree`!! Keep up the awesome work and all the awesome answers!!

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

As you wanted the result of a cast to `[System.IO.FileInfo]`, you can instead use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7.2), which will also return a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object, but with resolved relative paths *as expected*. It will also incorporate some error detection (invalid characters or non-existent path etc.).

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents> (Get-Item -LiteralPath '.\test.txt').FullName
C:\Users\User\Documents\test.txt
```