# Powershell: stripping a file name sometimes doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that is called from the command line.

```
script.ps1 "\\testfolder" "testinput" "xml" "xml2html.xsl" "testfile" "css"
```

The script uses these command line arguments:

```
param([string]$publish_folder, [string]$input_filename, [string]$input_ext, [string]$transformation_filename, [string]$output_filename, [string]$output_ext)
```

$input_filename and $output_filename may be a full path+filename, the filename only or the filename without extension.

```
$inputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename)
$inputPath=$publish_folder+"\"+$inputFileNameOnly+"."+$input_ext 
$outputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($output_filename) 
$outputPath=$publish_folder+"\"+$outputFileNameOnly+"."+$output_ext
```

When I run this locally, it works. Output path:

```
\\testfolder\testfile.css
```

When I run the same script in an AWS instance, it fails. $inputpath is calculated correctly, but Output path becomes:

```
\\testfolder\.
```

so both $output_filename and $output_ext are empty.

The paths are longer than `\\testfolder\`, but not long enough to cause trouble (about 150 characters). Total length of the arguments doesn't seem to be a problem either.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Different powershell versions?

Comment: `$outputFileNameOnly` and `$output_ext` are empty, you need to track back their origin.

Comment: @VasilNikolov I've confirmed $outputFileNameOnly and $output_ext are present in the command line arguments. I've updated the script to log the PS version and report back all of the arguments. Now I have to wait for a colleague to run the script in the AWS instance...

Answer (score 0):

```
$outputPath="$publish_folder+"\"+
```

Looks like you broke your concatenation here. Double-quote before $publish_folder.

Edit:
Can also be written like this if you don't want to concatenate (+)

```
$outputPath="$publish_folder\$outputFileNameOnly.$output_ext"
```

Anything in double-quotes should be expanded correctly.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo I added while editing the question, the " before $publish_folder shouldn't be there. Modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

I set up your script as a function and passed those parameters.

```
function rename {
    param(
        [string]$publish_folder, 
        [string]$input_filename,
        [string]$input_ext, 
        [string]$transformation_filename,
        [string]$output_filename, 
        [string]$output_ext
    )

    $inputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename)
    $inputPath = $publish_folder+"\"+$inputFileNameOnly+"."+$input_ext 
    $outputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($output_filename) 
    $outputPath = $publish_folder+"\"+$outputFileNameOnly+"."+$output_ext
    return $outputPath
}
```

Output is this...
`\\\\testfolder\\\\testfile.css`

Try passing `$publish_folder` without ending backslash

Edit: Sorry about formatting. Need some forum practice. =)

Comment: Checked the code, the path is being passed without a backslash. If `$publish_folder` was causing the problem, I'd also have wrong values in `$inputFileNameOnly`

Comment: AWS could be handling [System.IO.Path] differently. Could try a Split-Path/Replace and see if you get different results.

    $inputFileNameOnly = (Split-Path $input_filename -leaf) -replace "\.$input_ext$"

Comment: This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254096/system-io-fileinfo-and-relative-paths) can help you deal with `UNC` and `IO.FileInfo` as input parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

With some more testing, we found the cause of the problem.

```
$outputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($output_filename)
```

GetFileNameWithoutExtension fails (in the AWS instance) when `$output_filename` does not contain an extension. On my local machine this worked correctly.

So we added an extension to the command line argument and the script works correctly.