# Relative path when opening a file in Chrome via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome, path

I'm on Windows 10, and I'm trying to open a file with Chrome, however, PS always ends up sending it the relative path.

I'm running commands inside a directory called `phy`, and here is it's structure (relevant parts):

```sh
.
├── defaults.json
└── docs
    ├── 11-01-physics-rotation-and-revolution.html
    └── 11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
```

I tried each of the following commands in several ways.

- without Chrome on my PATH
- with Chrome on my PATH after reboot (specifically, the folder `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application` is on my user PATH)
- using `start chrome` instead of `chrome`
- with `\` instead of `/`

```
PS> chrome ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome Resolve-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> chrome Convert-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html
PS> Resolve-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html | chrome
PS> Convert-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html | chrome
```

After executing, the address bar of Chrome has either `./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html` (not the expanded version, it literally gets the `.` character), `Resolve-Path`, `Convert-Path`, or it's blank and I get the New Tab page.

The following commands work as expected:

```
PS> chrome
PS> chrome google.com
PS> chrome D:\username\Documents\edu\College\attempt-2\Exams\JEE\Notes\self\phy\docs\11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html  # this is the full path to the aforementioned phys directory
```

How do I get it to convert a relative path to an absolute one? Coming from Ubuntu, bash does this pretty much automatically.

Comment: Your call to `Convert-Path` should work correctly and is the way to resolve relative paths, it should work fine as long as you wrap it in `(...)`: `chrome.exe (Convert-Path ...)`

Comment: Damn @SantiagoSquarzon, that works. Thank you! Do you want to rewrite that as an answer (so we can mark it for any one searching this in the future)?

Comment: BTW @SantiagoSquarzon, is there a reason for you to specify `.exe` in your command? Or is it just what you're used-to?

Comment: No, no reason at all, I thought I saw `.exe` on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) should work properly and is the best way to handle relative paths, the only problem in this case is that you need to use the [Grouping operator `(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) so that the *expression* is evaluated first before we pass it to `chrome`:

```
chrome (Convert-Path ./docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a relative path to absolute, I use a small helper function:

```
function ConvertTo-AbsolutePath ([string]$Path) {
    if ($Path.StartsWith("~")) { 
        $Path = $Path.Substring(1)
        $current = $HOME
    }
    else { $current = $pwd.ProviderPath }
    if (-not ([System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($Path)) -or $Path -match '^\\[^\\]+') {
        return [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($current, $Path))
    }

    $Path
}
```

Usage:

```
$absPath = ConvertTo-AbsolutePath './docs/11-09-physics-mechanical-properties-of-materials.html'
```

Then use that as parameter to start chrome

Comment: How is this different from `Convert-Path` or `Resolve-Path`?

Comment: @eccentricOrange I wrote that function following the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70254096/9898643)

Comment: Theo, you can use `$PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)` as long as the function has `cmdletbinding` enabled