# get full path to PowerShell file parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell script. It takes a single path as a parameter. I want to manipulate that path and use it in another command, so I need the full path.

**I do not want to change the current directory.** I just want the full path of the given file.

I have worked with wonderful Java libraries such as [Picocli](https://picocli.info/), and I had assumed that merely setting the argument type to `System.IO.FileInfo` would make PowerShell figure out how where the path is (i.e. relative to the command or absolute). But apparently it isn't that smart, and `System.IO.FileInfo` casts the string to a file info and assumes that the parent directory for relative paths is the home directory. For example:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param([Parameter(Mandatory, HelpMessage="Archive Path")] [System.IO.FileInfo]$path)
…
Write-Output $path.FullName
```

I put this script in `C:\bin\extract-zip.ps1` and make sure `C:\bin\` is on the `PATH`. Then I go to the `C:\temp\` directory and run this command:

```
extract-foo foo.zip
```

It prints:

> C:\Users\user\foo.zip

This makes absolutely zero sense to me. I expected `C:\temp\foo.zip`.

So I guess I'll have to manually convert `$path` to an absolute path. If I know ahead of time that the user provided a relative path, I can do something like this (but I guess I would have to use type `String` instead of `System.IO.FileInfo`):

```
$path = Join-Path ([System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()) $path
```

But what if the user provided an absolute path? Isn't there some `resolve()` method that Do The Right Thing if the second argument is absolute? Or is there a method for detecting whether a path is absolute?

Here is the question: I want to convert a given path argument to an absolute path, whether the given path is absolute or relative, without changing the current directory.

I can find no Stack Overflow question that provides a direct answer. For [System.IO.FileInfo and Relative Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70254096) someone said to try `[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, '.\test.txt'))`, but nobody said if this works, and whether it works with both relative and absolute paths.

Comment: `Set-Location` and `Push-Location` do not update .NET current directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254096/system-io-fileinfo-and-relative-paths