# resolve filename to directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In Java I'm used to working with paths as semantic, platform-agnostic `Path` objects. If I have a directory `dir` and I want to find the filename `bar.txt` inside that directory, I'd use something like `dir.resolve("bar.txt")`, which would resolve `foo.bar` to the parent directory `dir`. I would *not* use `dir.toString() + "\bar.txt"`; this would be considered back practice, as it is error-prone and assumes a path separator `\` (which might be `/` on Linux for example).

In my PowerShell script the user passes an `$archive` variable containing some `foo.zip` archive. I expand it to `foo.zip.tmp` like this:

```
$dir = $archive + '.tmp'
Expand-Archive -Path $archive -DestinationPath $dir
```

At this point I want to work with a file `bar.txt` inside that new directory—that is, `$dir + '\bar.txt'`. But **what is the best-practices approach for resolving a known filename to some directory variable in PowerShell?** I hope this is not the best we can do, for the reasons explained above:

```
$barFile = $dir + '\bar.txt'
```

Comment: `Join-Path $dir 'bar.txt'`

Comment: Using [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) is good practice, but you can also take advantage of the fact that PowerShell accepts ``\`` and `/` _interchangeably_, on all supported platforms, so - when passing paths to _PowerShell_ commands - both `$dir + '/bar.txt'` and `$dir + '\bar.txt'` should work fine.

Comment: It would seem `Join-Path` works for simple filenames relative to a directory, so that answers this highly specific question. But is there no general `Resolve-Path` method (such as I get with Java `Path`) that would work correctly if the second argument were absolute? See my more general question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74908519 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with PowerShell, but a quick look at documentation, this might be a better practice to get rid of /:

```
Join-Path -Path "path" -ChildPath "childpath"
```

**Outputs:**
path\childpath

Source:
[learn microsoft powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: That's great, thanks. It's verbose, but seems to do what I want. Turns out I can even use it with the wildcard character, for example to recompress files back into an archive: `Compress-Archive -Path (Join-Path $dir '*') $outputArchive`.