# Rules around Get-ChildItem raising an error if -Path doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

What are the rules around `Get-ChildItem` throwing an error if a path doesn't exist?

I see the following, if I specify a path that doesn't exist:

```
PS C:\> gci -path C:\xyz -directory
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\xyz' because it does not exist.
PS C:\> gci -path C:\xyz\* -directory
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\xyz' because it does not exist.
PS C:\> gci -path C:\*\xyz -directory
PS C:\>
```

It seems that if the path is specified without a wildcard, or if the wildcard is used to specify a child of the non-existent directory, it throws an error. However, adding a wildcard for a parent directory of the non-existent directory results in `Get-ChildItem` not throwing an error.

Why does it not throw an error when the path is `C:\*\xyz`?

Comment: If you wanted to see the rules it follows you would need to check the code path for `GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` when `-Path` is used and `GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` when `-LiteralPath` is used. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71664740/15339544) shows how you can use those apis. You would also see the same behavior with `Resolve-Path C:\*\xyz` :) imo it makes perfect sense that `C:\*\xyz` doesn't throw an error because it's acting as a filter searching for any file or folder having the name `xyz` in any folder of ``C:\``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules are:

- ***Literal* paths** (those that do not contain [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) characters) that ***do not exist (as a whole)*** result in a *non-terminating* error.

  - This also applies if you use the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead of `-Path` to have a path explicitly treated literally (verbatim).
    This distinction only matters with literal paths that contain `[` and `]` (unlike in the wildcard language supported by `cmd.exe` and the native file-system APIs, these characters are metacharacters as well in PowerShell wildcards, used to form *character sets* or *ranges*).
  - As an aside:

    - I've deliberately avoided the wording "throwing" an error, given that PowerShell's [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement creates a script-*terminating* (fatal), which by default aborts execution overall, whereas *non-terminating* errors not only continue execution overall, but do not even abort the command at hand - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) for background information.
- ***Wildcard*-based paths** report a non-terminating error *if and only if* the **literal part *before* the first wildcard path component (if any) doesn't exist**.

  - Otherwise - rather than reporting an error - *nothing is output*.
  - In other words: What *follows* a wildcard-based path component does *not* trigger an error if it doesn't exist, even if the path up to the wildcard-based component *by itself* would match something.

Comment: Excellent comment in your aside.  I'll try to follow that advice in future, thanks.  I've edited the question title to replace "throwing an error" with "raising an error".

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SimonElms; my pleasure.